# Cookies for inferHtmlResources

Tags: gatling

I want to use Gatling for testing that I can access html resources.
In order to access given HTML, and its resources, I have to have some cookies defined.

I can set Cookies in http call with simple `.header("Cookie","test=test")`, but that way, it doesn't set cookie to inferred resources.

According to docs, you should be able to set cookies as:

> One might want to manually add or compute a cookie:
>
> exec(addCookie(Cookie("name", "value")))

but that doesn't work for me at all when used like this:

```
val someScenario = scenario("scenario").exec(
    exec(addCookie(Cookie("test","test"))),
    exec(http("httpcall").get("someUrl")))
```

Is there a way to set cookies for inferHtmlResources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are bound to a domain. If you don't specify one with `withDomain`, Gatling will use the one of the HttpProtocol `baseUrl`, and crash if you don't have one. So, a possible explanation is that this default domain doesn't match the one of your resources. If that's the case, set a proper domain on your cookie.

Otherwise, it could be a bug. Check the [bug tracker](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues), upgrade your Gatling version if you use an old one (as you don't specify the version you're using, which is bad), and give the [latest snapshot](http://gatling.io/#/download) a try. If nothing works, open an issue where you provide a way to reproduce.

Comment: I tried with setting the domain. Thanks anyway, I'll log bug tomorrow.

Comment: Fixed..., i just had wrong domain in withDomain set, sorry :)